# How to triple-boot Debian/Arch linux/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, partitioning, archlinux

I've been trying recently to partition my HDD to triple-boot Debian, Arch Linux and Ubuntu. 
Do i need to  make a boot partition, a root partition etc. for all the OSes or I just need to have one boot partition?

How can i partition my hard drive to triple boot Arch Linux/Debian/Ubuntu on an empty HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **a lot of effort** you can make a single `/boot` partition, and then be very, very, very careful with system updates that change the kernel image.  But, unless you're fine with fixing your system with every update of the system that installs a new kernel version(and `arch` notably has a kernel update every week) you should go for separate partitions.

All installs (`debian`, `ubuntu` and `arch`) will try to install a bootloader, but you should only install a single one on the MBR.  I will strongly recommend installing `grub` and from the `arch` distro installation.  First `grub` is easy to manage and there is a lot of documentation.  Second, unlike `ubuntu` `arch` will never automatically recreate the `grub` menu choices on system updates.

There is nothing wrong with making *exactly three partitions*, one for each OS.  And leaving `/boot` inside the partition of each OS.  Unless you have a 2TB+ disk, it will work.  During the installation of the bootloader `grub-probe` (e.g. `grub-probe --device /dev/sda3`, see `info grub-probe`) can detect all three OSes on their own partitions and add menu entries for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for the thourough answer

Comment: @grochmal "I will strongly recommend installing grub and from the arch distro installation." -> Is this saying those, who currently have a Windows partition, wishing to triple boot with the current Windows partition, and Arch, and another Ubuntu based distribution should let Arch install grub, hence Arch would be the first linux distro installed, and then the Ubuntu one? As opposed to just installing Ubuntu via the usual simple process, and then installing Arch, and then updating grub? If so, what advantage does letting Arch install grub have?

Comment: @Abdul - newest version?  GRUB config is also backwards compatible.

Comment: @grochmal I guess, is there any advantage of installing arch first, then Ubuntu, vs the opposite? (If you wanna retain the Windows partition as well)

Comment: @Abdul - Nope, I cannot see any advantages in the order of installation.  I can see reasons to be overly careful with the Ubuntu install, it has the bad habit of deciding on things without consulting you.  e.g. re-encrypting LUKS partitions **on top of your current data** with its own installation generated keys (that has been fixed in the recent installs though).

Comment: @grochmal I see, so it'd be better to install Ubuntu first. Thanks!